# Android: How to set button image of button in application

Tags: android

Currently I have this:  front_card_display.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.large_card_0);

However, I want to have large_card_"0" to be flexible meaning that I want it to be based on a variable or change when needed. It could be 1 , 2 , 3 .. etc. What is the best way on doing this. I have also tried creating a r.string but it seems to not work. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: Copy all the drawable images in drawable folder like mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi depends on resolution,t will be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want getIdentifier(). [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

This is the only way I know, and it works well enough.

EDIT: Example

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 118; i++) {
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("element" + i, "id", this.getPackageName());
        Button preview = (Button) findViewById(id);
        //...

    }
```

Here's some code. In my case, I have 118 buttons named element1, element2, element3 and so on. You can see how i use the "i" as a variable to iterate through them all

Comment: Hi Rahl_Pryde, can you give me an example on how to use this method?

Comment: Hi Rahl_Pyrde, your example helped a lot but there is still one thing that is giving me an error  "this.getPackageName())";   it Says that getPackageName() is an undefined method

Comment: Maybe getApplicationContext().getPackageName(); can work for you, but I've had no problem with the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up a switch statement that sets your drawableId.

```
    private int getDrawableId(int yourVariableToSwitchOn) {

        int drawableId;
        switch(yourVariableToSwitchOn) {
            case CASE_0:
               drawableId = R.drawable.large_card_0;
               break;
            case CASE_1:
               drawableId = R.drawable.large_card_1;
               break;
            case CASE_2:
               drawableId = R.drawable.large_card_2;
               break;
            case CASE_3:
               drawableId = R.drawable.large_card_3;
               break;
         }
         return drawableId;
    }
```

Then simply set your background `front_card_display.setBackgroundResource(getDrawableId(someVariableToControlResource));`

Comment: hi TyFlyGuy, Why is drawableId an int type. Thanks for your reponse

Comment: R.drawable.large_card_0 or whatever resource you are trying to grab from drawable is returned as an int. I will edit this slightly.